# Mockito not throwing exception using thenThrow

Tags: java, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock the method of service layer.

trying to mock the following line of code

```
boolean status= accountDAO.updateAccount(Account acct);
```

And To mock this I am using

```
Mockito.when(accountDAO.updateAccount(Account acct)).thenThrow(new DataBaseException());
```

But the problem is when code comes to the line `boolean status= accountDAO.updateAccount(Account acct);`, no exception gets thrown, it just works the normal way, without throwing an exception. Ideally an exception should be thrown, because I have mocked it to throw Database exception.

While there is another method "find account", i.e

```
Account acc=accountDAO.find(Account.class,accountId);
```

for this method the exception is being thrown successfully using mocikto, but for the update method it is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. Post real code.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both, the production code and the test. I suspect that you do not replace the dependency with the mock, but without seeing the complete code this is just a guess.

Comment: just to be sure can you compare the mocked instance with the instance that your business layer has using debug mode. If the instances are different then it means that you need to pass your mocked instance to business layer first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that your code looks like this:

```
Account acct = ...
Mockito.when(accountDAO.updateAccount(acct)).thenThrow(new DataBaseException());
```

This will throw an exception if you execute above method only with `Account acct`, other objects will not throw anything. So if you are executing this method with different object, nothing will happen.

To check this, you can define a rule, that any execution of this method, with any instance of `Account` will throw an exception:

```
 Mockito.when(accountDAO.updateAccount(Mockito.any(Account.class))).thenThrow(new DataBaseException());
```

Comment: Thanks, this rule worked for me. May be I was passing the wrong object.

Comment: You saved my day! +1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this line

```
Mockito.when(accountDAO.updateAccount(Account acct)).thenThrow(new DataBaseException());
```

should not compile. You must specify some value as an argument to `updateAccount()` call, for example:

```
Mockito.when(accountDAO.updateAccount(Mockito.any(Account.class))).thenThrow(new DataBaseException());
```

This would mean 'when `updateAccount()` is called with any `Account` argument, then throw'.